# Updated Data Not Saving In MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Updated Data Not Saving In MongoDB

##### GET Food Details

- router.route("/food/:id").get(getfoodDetails)
- here the request status is false by default.
- "status": false,
  **PostMan Response**

```bash
{
    "success": true,
    "food": {
        "_id": "6310c11a25659a73a9323135",
        "name": "chowmin",
        "description": "this is desc..",
        "ratings": 0,
        "category": "chineese",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "owner": "hotel belmuri",
        "image": [],
        "requests": [
            {
                "user": "63105a8dfca318c1972bcc29",
                "name": "Vollunteer",
                "comment": "want this for poor people",
                "status": false,
                "_id": "6310c527bed4bba6a608b29f"
            },
            {
                "user": "632884611816c85c14edcd2f",
                "name": "Ankita",
                "comment": "want this for poor people",
                "status": false,
                "_id": "6329cec0b2b6e6c02927d3e6"
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2022-09-01T14:26:34.396Z",
        "__v": 2,
        "numOfRequests": 2
    }
}
```

##### PUT  | Accept Food request

- router.route("/request/accept/:id").put(isAuthenticatedUser,authorizeRoles("hotel"),acceptFoodRequest)
- https://github.com/AnkitaMalik22/hsfd-system/blob/main/backend/controllers/foodControllers.js#L135
- here i am trying to change the request status from false to true.
- "status": true,

**PostMan Response**

```bash
{
    "success": true,
    "food": {
        "_id": "6310c11a25659a73a9323135",
        "name": "chowmin",
        "description": "this is desc..",
        "ratings": 0,
        "category": "chineese",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "owner": "hotel belmuri",
        "image": [],
        "requests": [
            {
                "user": "63105a8dfca318c1972bcc29",
                "name": "Vollunteer",
                "comment": "want this for poor people",
                "status": true,
                "_id": "6310c527bed4bba6a608b29f"
            },
            {
                "user": "632884611816c85c14edcd2f",
                "name": "Ankita",
                "comment": "want this for poor people",
                "status": false,
                "_id": "6329cec0b2b6e6c02927d3e6"
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2022-09-01T14:26:34.396Z",
        "__v": 2,
        "numOfRequests": 2
    }
}
```

It's Changed to  **"status": true** ! But the problem is it's not saving in MongoDb .

When i'm requesting  get food details again it's showing **"status": false**

Comment: `Food.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{new:true, runValidators:true, useFindAndModify:false})` doesn't look like it updates `"status"`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.